# Is it possible to send an email using sendgrid in Azure without calling context.done?

Tags: javascript, azure, sendgrid

I am using the azure portal to write an azure function to go through a database and send multiple emails using sendgrid for each database entry.  I have been able to send one email using sendgrid by placing the following code inside my foreach loop:

```
var message = {
         "personalizations": [ { "to": [ { "email": "testto@gmail.com"     } ] } ],
    from: { email: "testfrom@gmail.com" },        
    subject: "Azure news",
    content: [{
        type: 'text/plain',
        value: order
    }]
};

context.done(null, {message});
```

The problem is that calling context.done(null,{message}) to send the email using sendgrid ends my function.  Which means that I am only able to send one email.

Is it possible to use something other than context.done to send emails using sendgrid so that I can send multiple emails from within the function?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you can use context.bindings.message (or whatever name you gave your binding for sendgrid).